# Getting error while uploading app on ionic.io

Tags: android, ios, angularjs, ionic-framework

I am creating an app in which i have to use push notification 
after creating app i am trying do upload it but there are some problems,

1>after uploading i am not getting "successfully uploaded " message

2>although i can see my app on ionic view(ionic .io)

3>but at the bottom of app it is saying

```
"This app is not live. Check out our Getting Started guide."
```

how can i solve this

i have used this plugin

1>ionic add ionic-platform-web-client

2>ionic plugin add phonegap-plugin-push

3>ionic io init

after this it is showing my app io ionic app but

```
"This app is not live. Check out our Getting Started guide.
```

Comment: Again go to `Getting Started guide` and try to figure out any mistake are you doing or you can contact to ionic also for help http://ionic.io/support

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must first do **ionic login from the console** ,

If your account is open from in chrome or any browser then logout first and then login from cmd your app will be live

even if this is not work then check out the link below for some reference  and your app will run

http://docs.ionic.io/